# Visual Studio Code C++ remove 'define' in c_cpp_properties.json

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I know it is possible to add defines for Visual Studio Code in c_cpp_properties.json and I manually define `__GNUC__` for my code, but is it possible to undo/remove defines that Visual Studio Code assumes for itself? For example if I set `intelliSenseMode` to `clang-x64` the macro `__clang__` is defined which completely destroys my intellisense because I don't have appropriate include files for libraries I use and include selection for `__clang__` happens before `__GNUC__`. Same for `msvc-x64` value. If I manually `#undef __clang__` in my include files then everything is perfect.

Is it possible to undo macro in Visual Studio Code configuration?

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes

First, create a header file called, say, `vscode-preinclude.h`.  Put it anywhere; I'll assume it is in the workspace folder (the one that also has `.vscode` in it).  Inside that file use `#undef` to undefine the symbols you need turned off.  Example:

```cpp
#undef __clang__
```

Next, use the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and open "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)".  Go down to the bottom and open "Advanced Settings".  Scroll down to "Forced include", and add a line:

```
${workspaceFolder}/vscode-preinclude.h
```

That's it!

#### Troubleshooting

If it doesn't work, take a look at the output of the "C/C++: Log Diagnostics" command.  It should show something like:

```
    Forced Includes:
        D:\WRK\LEARN\VSCODE\CPPHELLO\VSCODE-PREINCLUDE.H
```

in its output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the C++ extension to auto-configure your system includes & defines, you can set `"compilerPath": ""` for your configuration in your `c_cpp_properties.json` and the extension will stop auto-configuring you.